# How to use new-bind with addeventListeners in ES6 - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eventhandler

I am trying to add addEventlistener to DOM element which has #addButton id.I am using new binding method in ES6 but this does not work. How to call add function?

```
class ToDoApp {
constructor (settings) {
    if (!settings) {
        throw 'Todo App requires settings object';
    }
    this.addButtonHandler = document.querySelector(settings.addButtonSelector);
    this.addButtonHandler.addEventListener('click', this.add);

}
add = () => {
    console.log('heello');
 }
}

 const myTodo = new ToDoApp({
inputSelector: '#input',
addButtonSelector: '#addButton',
deleteButtonSelector: '#delete',
listContainerSelector: '#list'
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="imputArea">
        <form action="index.html" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="input" />
            <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="listArea">
        <ul id="list">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <p id="task">Task 1</p>
                <input type="button" id="delete" value="X" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Works fine if button exists when you create `newTodo`. What does "doesn't work" mean...any errors?

Comment: "*new binding method in ES6*" - what are you talking about?

Comment: "*but this does not work*" - what exactly does not work? How does your DOM look like (html markup) when you run this code? Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are getting this error due to the fact that element would not exist when you create an instance of newTodo. you might want to put null check for the button you are trying to add event listener to.

```
class ToDoApp {
    constructor(settings) {
        if (!settings) {
            throw 'Todo App requires settings object';
        }
        this.addButtonHandler = document.querySelector(settings.addButtonSelector);
        if (this.addButtonHandler) {
            this.addButtonHandler.addEventListener('click', this.add);
        } else {
            throw "Element you want to add event listener to doesn't exist";
        }

    }
    add = () => {
        console.log('heello');
    }
}

const myTodo = new ToDoApp({
    inputSelector: '#input',
    addButtonSelector: '#addButton',
    deleteButtonSelector: '#delete',
    listContainerSelector: '#list'
});
```

Comment: I am getting "SyntaxError: fields are not currently supported". Also my HTML code as follows;

Comment: @SemihÖzden That's because `add = () => {` *is* a syntax error. Instead, put `this.add = () => {` in your constructor.

Comment: I have solved the problem. When I open the project with google chrome, it works well but in the firefox it does not work. It gives syntax error.

Comment: @SemihÖzden this is because `public class fields syntax` javascript is not yet supported in firefox. you can see status here: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6001727933251584. I you want to run this code in all browser, I would recommend you to transpile using bable.

Comment: Thank you so much @KaranVerma